# Yaml file value is not loading using jackson in java

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, pojo, snakeyaml

I want to load a yaml file & store it in Config.java.

Here is my yaml file: (Its much bigger. I am giving a simplified version)

```
---
application:
  admin:
    jobInterValTime: 1440
    customer: lc
system:
  mongo:
    host: localhost
    port: 27017
    dbName: LC_Test
    collections:
      groupsCollection: groups
      membershipCollection: memberships
      personsCollection: persons
```

Here is Config.java:

```
public class Config {
  private Application application;
  private System system;
  //Getter setter
}
```

Application.java

```
public class Application {
    private Admin admin;    
    //Getter Setter
}
```

Admin.java

```
public class Admin {
    private String jobInterValTime;
    private String customer;
    //Getter Setter
}
```

System.java

```
public class System {

    private Mongo mongo;       
    //Getter Setter
}
```

Mongo.java

```
public class Mongo {
    private String host;
    private String port;
    private String dbName;
    private Map<String, String> collections;
    //Getter Setter
}
```

But the `application` & `system` object inside `Config.java` is coming null.No exception is happening. Can anybody help?

Here is what I  have written.

```
Config config = null;
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
try{
    config = objectMapper.readValue(new File("src/test/java/resources/test1.yaml"), Config.class);
    //System.out.println(application.getAdmin().getCustomer());
    // System.out.println(unidataConfig.getApplication().getAdmin().getCustomer());

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The mistake was very stupid. In one setter method I have written like this: `var1 = var1` instead of `this.var1 = var1`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the root cause here, code looks good. But one thing you could try is to read contents as `Map` or `JsonNode` first, and see how structure looks like. There may well be a mismatch.